# I am having issues trying to rewrite this JavaScript click event in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a small piece of JavaScript code that is used to toggle a repsonsive navigation menu.

```
const toggleNavigation = document.getElementsByClassName('navigation-icon')[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0]

toggleNavigation.addEventListener('click', () => {
navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

I want to rewrite this for Vue. I have done event handling in Vue before, but it is difficult for me to relate the examples in the guide to this particular piece of code.

What I tried was to use the v-on directive:

```
<template>

<div class="navigation-icon" @click="toggleNavigation">
    <i class="pi pi-bars"></i>
</div>

</template>

<script>

export default {

    setup() {

        const toggleNavigation = document.getElementsByClassName('navigation-icon')[0]

        const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0]

        if (toggleNavigation) () => {

        navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')

    }

    return {

        toggleNavigation,

        navbarLinks

    }

}

}

</script>
```

What is the correct way to write this?

Comment: You can take reference from the vue3 docs for handling event:https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/events.html#event-handling

Answer (score 1):

In your case `toggleNavigation` is not a function, so it make no sense to write: `@click="toggleNavigation"`

Please take a look at the `handling event` reference from the Vue.js V3 docs: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/events.html#event-handling

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="navigation-icon" @click="toggleNavigation">
    <i class="pi pi-bars"></i>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      toggleNavigation() {
        // Handle the toggle logic here
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Now if you want to emit something out of this component to a parent component, use the event emitter inside the `toggleNavigation()` method. More on this [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html).

```
toggleNavigation() {
  this.$emit('toggled')
}
```

In the parent component, catch the emitted event like this:

```
<template>
  <ChildComponent @toggled="toggled" />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      toggled() {
        // Handle the toggle logic here
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

FYI: You can choose to pass optional params too while emitting, just add them like this: `this.$emit('toggled', param1, param2)`.